Error: (null): cannot install "flutter": classic confinement requires snaps under /snap or symlink from
I am trying to install flutter on Manjaro but am receiving the following error from the pamac gui:
(null): cannot install "flutter": classic confinement requires snaps under /snap or symlink from


Ensure that the snapd service is running:
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket

Manjaro does not create the /snap directory by default which is required for classic confinement.  Create a symlink so that classic confinement snaps can find their required directory structure.
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap

Proceed with the install:
snap install --classic flutter

